# How do I convert a jsonb column into a jsonb[] column?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a table by the name of chat with a column called messages. Each row stores a user's chat statistics, and messages is (if not apparent already) an array of objects containing information on each message. The problem is, I created this column long before I completely understood Postgressql. I remembered that JSON's could be arrays, and so I did not think to add the [] after the jsonb column type.

Today, a month from this dumb mistake I attempted to get a gigantic array of all of the messages combined for statistical purposes, but realized that I could not easily do so without a true Postgressql array.

How can I convert this column to the jsonb[] type? Resetting the database is not an option; over 200,000 messages have already been created. When attempting to edit it in the properties section of the table, my only given options are 'json' and 'jsonb'.

Comment: Your description of the model is too general but it seems the only reasonably solution is to create a new table for messages in relation one-to-many from the main table. `jsonb[]` is surely a bad idea and definitely won't simplify the issue.

Comment: `jsonb[]` almost never makes sense - store the array inside the JSON column

Answer (score 0):

> I attempted to get a gigantic array of all of the messages combined for statistical purposes, but realized that I could not easily do so without a true Postgressql array.

This sounds suspicious. I would expect that you want *rows* of all the messages. Take a look at the [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) function. I use it below to do as you requested.

```sql
-- setup
CREATE TABLE chat (id int, messages jsonb);

INSERT INTO chat VAlUES
  (1, '[{"some":"content"},{"more":"stuff"}]'),
  (2, '["maybe","this"]');

-- solution
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE chat RENAME messages TO messages_old;
ALTER TABLE chat ADD messages jsonb[];

UPDATE chat
  SET messages = (SELECT array_agg(m) FROM jsonb_array_elements(messages_old) m);

ALTER TABLE chat
  ALTER messages SET NOT NULL,
  DROP messages_old;
COMMIT;

-- result
SELECT * FROM chat;
/*
 id |                      messages                       
----+-----------------------------------------------------
  1 | {"{\"some\": \"content\"}","{\"more\": \"stuff\"}"}
  2 | {"\"maybe\"","\"this\""}
(2 rows)
*/
```